# вставить запись если не существует (php,mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

вот есть такой код, как правильно в $query реализовать вставку записи если  она не существует.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require 'connect.php';
    createMessage();
}
function createMessage(){
    global $connect;
    $fname_lastname = $_POST["fname_lastname"];
    $query="INSERT INTO quest_db (fname_lastname) VALUES ('$fname_lastname');";
    mysqli_query ($connect,$query)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> как правильно реализовать вставку записи если она не существует

1. Добавить уникальный индекс на вставляемое поле
2. Добавить модификатор IGNORE к запросу INSERT

   ```
   $query="INSERT IGNORE INTO quest_db (fname_lastname) VALUES (...);";
   ```

Вставка произойдет только если в поле fname_lastname нет вставляемого значения.

Comment: Немного не понял, у меня есть в бд 2 поля, это id с автоинкрементом, ну и поле с фамилией и именем, которая вытягивается в  андроид приложении. И не понял почему VALUES пустое, думал что уникальный индекс в таблице заменяет автоинкремент. И как добавить этот самый индекс в вставляемое поле. Сорри за глупые вопросы но php, это новое)

Comment: `как добавить этот самый индекс в вставляемое поле` Запросом. `php, это новое` Это MySQL, а не PHP.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Вопрос решен